# SQL DECODE function with comparison operator

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone help me to understand the below SQL output?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dual 
WHERE SYSDATE >= DECODE(NVL(1,0),0,NULL,SYSDATE);
-- This returns row

SELECT * 
FROM dual 
WHERE SYSDATE <= DECODE(NVL(1,0),0,NULL,SYSDATE); 
-- No output if we use <= 

SELECT * 
FROM dual 
WHERE SYSDATE <= DECODE(NVL(1,0),0,SYSDATE,SYSDATE);
-- This returns row
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with the data type that `decode` returns.  That is based on the data type of the first optional return but it defaults to `varchar2`.  So the expression (I'm replacing `nvl(1,0)` with `1` because it doesn't change the behavior and simplifies the expression)

```
DECODE(1,0,NULL,SYSDATE)
```

returns a `varchar2` value.  That means that the query effectively becomes

```
select *
  from dual
 where sysdate <= to_char(sysdate);
```

which you can see if you look at the plan

```
explain plan for
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE SYSDATE <= DECODE(1,0,null,SYSDATE); 

select * from table( dbms_xplan.display() );

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 4034615273
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER          |      |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(SYSDATE@!<=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!))
```

If you set your `nls_date_format` to something that includes the time component of the date, your query will return a row because now the implicit cast doesn't lose the time information.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

SELECT 1 "null" FROM dual WHERE SYSDATE <= DECODE(1,0,null,SYSDATE); 

null
1
```

Alternately, you can have the `decode` return the correct data type by doing an explicit cast

```
SELECT 1 "cast(null)" 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE SYSDATE <= DECODE(1,0,cast(null as date),SYSDATE);
```

That will return a row regardless of the session's `nls_date_format` because the `decode` will now return a `date` data type and you're comparing a `date` to a `date`.  That's also why `decode(1,0,sysdate,sysdate)` worked-- because that `decode` expression also returns a `date`.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM dual 
WHERE SYSDATE >= DECODE(1,0,NULL,SYSDATE); --may I know how it returns when we use >=?

Comment: TO_CHAR(SYSDATE) < SYSDATE ... Got it... Thank you for the clarification